# django modeltranslation 404

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n, django-modeltranslation

I'm trying to set up my app in two languages, however I'm getting 404 error on all app's urls, even though I've set up another app a while ago the exact same way.

models.py:

```
class New(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, editable=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # Newly created object, so set slug
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super(New, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

translation.py:

```
class NewTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('title','text')

translator.register(New, NewTranslationOptions)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^categories/$', 'products.views.categories_index', name='categories_index'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'products.views.specific_category', name='specific_category'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<product_slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'products.views.specific_product', name='specific_product'),

    url(r'^news/$', 'news.views.news_index', name='news_index'),
    url(r'^news/(?P<news_slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'news.views.specific_new', name='specific_new'),
)
```

Here you can also see urls of my other app products, it works just fine. If you need anything else please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `specific_category` and `specific_product` url patterns are catching urls from `news` app:

```
>>> re.match("(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)", "news").groups()
('news',)
```

Reorder your urls patterns:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^categories/$', 'products.views.categories_index', name='categories_index'),

    url(r'^news/$', 'news.views.news_index', name='news_index'),
    url(r'^news/(?P<news_slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'news.views.specific_new', name='specific_new'),

    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'products.views.specific_category', name='specific_category'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<product_slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'products.views.specific_product', name='specific_product'),
)
```

Or, consider adding `category/` prefix to patterns from `products` app:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'products.views.specific_category', name='specific_category'),
url(r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<product_slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'products.views.specific_product', name='specific_product'),
```